# How to use twitter style follow feature in rails with mongoid 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am using mongoid 3.x with rails 3.2

I want to build twitter style follow user feature, none of the mongoid follow gems in rails work on mongoid 3.0 version as it supports 2.x

any suggestions on this feature implementation with mongoid 3.x and rails 3.2

Comment: have you checked https://www.ruby-toolbox.com

Answer (score 0):

Check out this book from Rick Copeland:
[http://www.amazon.com/MongoDB-Applied-Design-Patterns-Copeland/dp/1449340040/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1373395463&sr=8-1&keywords=mongodb+design+patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449340040)

The book isn't Rails/Ruby/Mongoid specific but the concepts should translate fairly easy for you. Rick is an avid Python guy and strong member of the MongoDB community. In his book there's actually a whole chapter in there dedicated to creating a social follower/following style model.

Hope that helps.

Edit: This presentation on "Advanced Schema Design" may be of use to you also. I'm going to be doing a blog post on this topic in the near future, but you can get most of the content here form Jared's talk.

http://www.slideshare.net/jrosoff/mongodb-advanced-schema-design-inboxes